# Get access to the inserted row after doing an insert using sqlite3_exec on iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 in my application and was wondering if there is any better way to access a row that has just been inserted using sqlite3_exec other than just doing a select after the insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the last_insert_rowid() function ?  http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid